# Imagecache preset table

Tags: media

I got my database crashed and fixed it, but some tables missed some of its data. one of these tables are the table that contains the preset values for imagecache (imagecache v 1.6.2.1, Drupal 6.19).

```
mysql> select * from imagecache_preset;

+----------+-----------------------------------------+
| presetid | presetname                              |
+----------+-----------------------------------------+
|        1 | article_headline_main                   |
|        2 | article_headline_thumb                  |
|        3 | article_headline_node                   |
|        4 | article_behind_the_news_old             |
|        5 | article_main_news_old                   |
```

By editing any of the above presets, i found that it is UNSET and I have to respecify action, height and width.
I have a dump of my database, but I need to know the table that contains the preset values so I can get them back from the backup. Which database table is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `imagechache_action` table, that should have the information you are looking for.